# undefined reference error while installing opencv 2.4.10 in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: opencv, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my 32 bit hp Pavilion dv4000 laptop. I am trying to install OpenCV 2.4.10 but I am getting the same below error even after following many tutorials.
  when I give "make" command to install opencv, terminal terminates with this error after 17% completion. Can anybody suggest how can I fix it?

```
 Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_perf_imgproc
//usr/local/lib/libv4l2.so.0: undefined reference to `v4lconvert_fixup_fmt'
//usr/local/lib/libv4l2.so.0: undefined reference to `v4lconvert_vidioc_s_ext_ctrls'
//usr/local/lib/libv4l2.so.0: undefined reference to `v4lconvert_vidioc_g_ext_ctrls'
//usr/local/lib/libv4l2.so.0: undefined reference to `v4lconvert_vidioc_try_ext_ctrls'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_perf_imgproc] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_imgproc.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following options:

1. Use OpenCV 2.4.9 instead
2. Run `sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev`

Or use the following steps, which I have used successfully to install OpenCV in Ubuntu 14.04, 12.04 and Debian Wheezy

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential make cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config python python-dev python-numpy libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev
cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/itseez/opencv
mv opencv /opt
cd /opt/opencv
git checkout 2.4.10.1 #or whatever version you want
sudo mkdir build
cd build
sudo cmake -j4 -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
sudo make -j4
sudo make -j4 install
sudo ldconfig
```

Refer to this http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html

Comment: yes. before I had installed opencv 2.4.9 successfully. But i was not able to run a python script wherein i was getting an error "illegal instruction (core dumped)". So i had thought 2.4.9 can't run this script. So tried to install opencv 2.4.10. I tried with almost all tutorials but was getting above error. I was struggling a lot from a weak to clear this error. Now i have changed my OS to 12.04 version. now iam successful in installing opencv 2.4.10.

Comment: OK, good. I'm pretty sure the illegal instruction error would be unrelated to the OpenCV version - it might be a sign of a deeper problem, perhaps you could ask a different question on the site about that. But anyway if an answer to a question solves the problem, you should click the tick to mark it as accepted.